# What is the authority in the UK?

Tags: easa, caa-uk-regulations

Is the United Kingdom subject to the EASA's authority or the CAA's (Civil Aviation Authority) authority?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EASA: this is a European Union body, so yes, the UK is a member state.

CAA: There are many Civil Aviation Authorities worldwide, basically each is a national entity within the corresponding state. So, specifically for the UK, yes, there exists a body known as CAA that is a state entity, formally independent but in practice dependent on the UK Government (Dept. of Transport). Their web page is: http://www.caa.co.uk/

Due to the complex configuration of EU law, both EASA and the UK CAA can have their word to say on operations within UK territory. Though, as CAA say themselves:

> The CAA works closely with the European Aviation Safety Agency (EASA) to promote the highest common standards of safety and environmental protection in civil aviation.

Comment: The last link should probably be put in as a comment, since that's an answer to a separate question that has now been edited out.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Indeed, thanks for the heads-up. For a list of all Aviation Authorities, Wikipedia has a list of CAA bodies here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_civil_aviation_authorities